# Phantomjs: how can I get Casperjs to work on my webapp

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Currently as I play with Phantomjs/CasperJS, its all done through the console per their examples.

Is it a way for me to use it in conjunction with my current web application?

Example: Use my site to fill out a form, that info gets sent to CasperJS, casper then returns a response to the site. Etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

If the idea is to ease recording your test cases, you may want to have a look at [resurectio](https://github.com/casperjs/resurrectio), which is a *CasperJS test recorder Chrome extension*.